# Custom array name

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to make an array that has data stored in itself, and then I'd like to request the data by just calling an users their id `myarray[userId].language`.

This is the code I'm using but how can I make it so myId actually becomes someones id and not just a string?

```
var myId = 62;
var users = [];

users.push({myId:{ //myId should be 62
    language:"Dutch",
    born:1999
}});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xad6qaL1/)

Comment: what do you want to do ?
this code is not similar to the thing that you want !

Comment: Don't use push. `users[myId] = {
    language:"Dutch",
    born:1999
};`

Comment: I want to push my data that when I request the id from the users array like so: `users[62]` that it will return the array `{language: "Dutch", born: 1999}`

Comment: @mplungjan This doesn't look like a typo, and the problem is definitely reproducible.

Comment: @4castle - _caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced_

Comment: @mplungjan is there any difference? I've always used `push` till this point.

Comment: Then you would have `users[0] = {}; users[0][myId]={ //myId should be 62
    language:"Dutch",
    born:1999
}` which would not allow you to do users[62]

Comment: @mplungjan Please don't use that close reason for questions where the problem is reproducible. Just because your comment shows how to fix the problem, it doesn't mean the question should be closed.

Comment: @4castle - I believe that is up to my discretion to use that - using push on an object is not working. There are no other close reasons for something simple that does not work because of wrong assumption

Comment: @mplungjan There are no other close reasons because it's an invalid close reason. Do not close questions just because they are obvious to you. The OP had no idea how to fix their problem, so it is a valid question.

Comment: @MartijnEbbens if you push 62 other users you will have what you want: `var users = [];
users.push({ language:"Dutch",
    born:1999
});` this will be user 0

Comment: @4castle - I disagree. It was closed as a dupe anyway. I could have hammerclosed it as a dupe to had I looked

Comment: @mplungjan Thanks, it works, I knew this question should be arround somewhere else but I really couldn't find the right termology to find the question and didn't really knew what to look for.

Comment: You normally don't and you cannot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an object instead of an array and take the id as key for the object.

```js
var myId = 62,
    users = {};

users[myId] = {
    language: "Dutch",
    born: 1999
};

console.log(users);
console.log(users[myId].language);
```

Comment: user = [] will also allow [62]

Comment: @mplungjan, right with sparse array. (which is not wanted, or needed ...?)

Comment: Unless he has the others too ;)

Comment: @mplungjan, right. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can now evaluate expressions in object literal property names by using square brackets.

```js
var myId = 62;
var users = [];

users.push({
  [myId]: { //myId is 62
    language: "Dutch",
    born: 1999
  }
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(users, null, 2));
```

Use a transpiler if you need to support legacy engines.

---

Of course you can do this without `.push()` too.

```js
var myId = 62;
var users = [{
  [myId]: { //myId is 62
    language: "Dutch",
    born: 1999
  }
}];

console.log(JSON.stringify(users, null, 2));
```

Comment: Ouch.. That is new

Comment: And now get users[62]